# How to load a view / a control once for multiple pages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I made a navigation bar for my Xamarin.Forms app's pages like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.BottomNavView">
  <Button Text="Page 1"
          Clicked="OnPage1" />
  <Button Text="Page 2"
          Clicked="OnPage2" />
</StackLayout>
```

But when I am opening different pages which include it like this:

```
  <local:BottomNavView></local:BottomNavView>
```

It flashes - gets reloaded with the whole page every time.
Is there a way to prevent this, to load it only once for all pages at the app startup? How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In Xaml, doing this

```xml
<local:BottomNavView/>
```

is the `c#` equivalent of

```cs
new BottomNavView ();
```

so it is effectively created every time you use it.

> NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT DO WHAT IS DESCRIBED BELOW

You could create your view once in e.g. your `Application` `ResourceDictionary`

```xml
...
<Application.ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:BottomNavView x:Key="bottomNavView" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.ResourceDictionary>
```

and then reuse it as a `StaticResource`

```xml
<ContentView Content="{StaticResource bottomNavView}" />
```

and the same object instance would be shared across the views. But as `Xamarin.Forms` is not built to support rendering the same view instance simultaneously (this is different from reusing views), it will probably not work well at all. So don't do that.